# could not find ruby, failed to process package orgen

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find Ruby (missing: RUBY_INCLUDE_DIR RUBY_LIBRARY
  RUBY_CONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR) (found version "2.3.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindRuby.cmake:273 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/robot/ws/underlay_isolated/build_isolated/orogen/install/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

<== Failed to process package 'orogen': 
  Command '['/home/robot/ws/underlay_isolated/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/robot/ws/underlay_isolated/src/orocos/orocos_toolchain/orogen', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/robot/ws/underlay_isolated/install_isolated', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/robot/ws/underlay_isolated/build_isolated/orogen && /home/robot/ws/underlay_isolated/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /home/robot/ws/underlay_isolated/src/orocos/orocos_toolchain/orogen -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/robot/ws/underlay_isolated/install_isolated -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.
```

when i am trying to build orocos toolchain from source as in [this](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration) link. I am using ubuntu 16.06 with ros kinetic. Before this i have used orocoes with ros indigo . But now i am unable to install it in ros kinetic. So what should i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282268/could-not-find-ruby,-failed-to-process-package-orgen/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, since the answe can be helpful to others, i'll post the solution which solved my problem.
To solve this ruby problem i just installed below two packages:

```
apt-get install ruby-dev
gem install rake hoe
```

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2018-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1